# How to apply fallback font to all text, not only missing characters

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to apply fallback font to entire paragraph? For example, I have some text where can be latin or cyrillic or both symbols. I want to use one font only with latin text and another with cyrillic/mixed. Is it possible?

Here is an example:

```css
p {
    font-family: Lato, Montserrat;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Some latin text.</p>
    <p>Здесь кирилица.</p>
    <p>And here some смешанный text.</p>
</body>
```

I want to apply Monterrat to whole 3rd paragraph

Comment: Hi @Ariakas, Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot provide you a better solution without your sample code or implementation

Comment: I think you would need javascript or a bit of server side processing for this one - like dynamically applying a certain class to the p tag, if it contains strange characters. The class then applies a different font via css.

Comment: You can create one css class and set font-family: Montserrat; to that class and apply that class to 3rd paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so if you would avoid a bit of font flickering at any cost, I would suggest server side processing here - if you want to save a bit of performance on your server, I would go client side with javascript:

the css:

```
.font-montserrat {
   font-family: Montserrat;
}
```

and the js with jQuery (server side, you would adapt this during rendering and put in some php function or whichever language you use):

```
 $('p').each(function() {
    var p = $(this);

    // here it is important to avoid other inline tags like b, i, span, etc
    var textWithoutOtherTags = p.text();

    // this is the main bit and one would simply test by a regular expression 
    // - this can be adapted as needed, at the moment it returns true, if a
    // single latin or cyrilic letter is present
    var hasLatin = /[a-z]/gi.test(textWithoutOtherTags);
    var hasCyrilic = /[а-я]/gi.test(textWithoutOtherTags);

    // now add the class depending on the containing characters
    if (hasLatin && hasCyrilic) {
       p.addClass('font-montserrat');
    }
 });
```

You can of course also do it easily without jQuery, but then please be aware of the b, i, strong, span and other inline tags, that might occur inside of your p, and filter them out before the regex testing.

Nice task ;)